# rename file while creating zip with grails ant

Tags: grails, ant

I have this ant code, but I want to write this into grails using antBuilder:

```html
<zip destfile="${dist}/manual.zip">
    <zipfileset dir="htdocs/manual" prefix="docs/user-guide"/>
    <zipfileset dir="." includes="ChangeLog27.txt"fullpath="docs/ChangeLog.txt"/>
    <zipfileset src="examples.zip" includes="**/*.html" prefix="docs/examples"/>
</zip>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me

new AntBuilder().zip(destFile: "${dist}/manual.zip") {

```
   zipfileset( dir:"htdocs/manual", includes: "${measureId}.xml", prefix:     "docs/user-guide" )

   zipfileset(  dir: "." , includes: "ChangeLog27.txt" ,fullpath: "docs/ChangeLog.txt" )

   zipfileset(src: "examples.zip",includes:"**/*.html",prefix:"docs/examples")
```

}